# Having trouble with Xdebug Stack Tracer on a Magento project

Tags: magento2, frontend, backend, xdebug, github

At the moment I'm running a Magento project on the 2.4.3 version and when i try to look at the frontend in any browser several tables from the Stack Tracer of Xdebug show up. Before this problem started I executed these two commands without knowing exactly what they do:

- git reset –hard
- git clean -fxd

I assumed i erase something and know these Stack Tracer appear.[image]

The problem persist on different projects that I've in the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you do some changes in the core.You have to follow these steps.

```
- composer update 
- sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/
```

Comment: I followed the steps but it did not work. The problem is still the same.

Comment: You can run s:up, s:di:c & c:f. Are you are trying to configure the xdebug?

Comment: I can run those commands without any problem, after those I initialized the fpm and the problem persists. No, I'm not trying to configure xdebug, what i want is to navigate through the project, but the StackTracers makes this impossible.

Comment: You should try this :                                                                                                                         

Run the below command w/o plugins updates it will work for you:

$ composer update --no-plugins --no-dev "magento-hackathon/magento-composer-installer"
OR    Check The PHP version. check your HTTP requests

You need to use same PHP version for both.

OR

Clear composer cache and the update composer.

composer clearcache
composer update
OR

Remove the vendor directory and the composer.lock and do a fresh install.

Comment: Thanks, before reading this comment I reinstalled PHP and Nginx and the problem was gone.